# How to use different databases (SQL Server, Oracle) from the same ASP.NET Core C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have C# code that performs basic CRUD Operations. I have a class library defined as AppDal which contains Db Operations (for SQL Server) and I am using namespace in C# code.

How can I use the same c# code to perform db operations for another db like Oracle. I want to set db name in `appsettings.json`. On that basis, it will decide which db to connect to. I will create another class library for another db like OracleDAL.

```
using AppDal; 

public IActionResult Add(CustomerModel input)
{
     ResponseModel response = new ResponseModel();

     Dal dal = new Dal();          
     int Id = dal.Add(input);

     if (Id > 0)
     {
         response.Id = Id;
         response.Message = "Record added successfully";
     }
     else
     {
         response.Message = "Record not added";
     }  

     return Json(response);
 }

 namespace AppDal
 {
      public int Add(CustomerModel input)
      {
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("@Id",input.Id),
                new SqlParameter("@CompanyId",input.CompanyId),         
                new SqlParameter("@Title",input.Title),              
                new SqlParameter("@Address",input.Address),         
            };

            int result = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(SqlHelper.defaultDB, CommandType.Text, CustomerQueries.Add, param).ToInt();
            return result;
        } 
}
```

It is possible if I create another application but that will increase maintenance time. I want to use same application.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to create an interface, example IDal that will have all your CRUD signature functions then create a concrete classes that inherit IDal for Sql Server and Oracle.

Then use the interface IDal as declared type for your Dal object. Example,

IDal Dal = DalForSqlServer() or IDal Dal = DalForOracle();

Answer (score 0):

the best way to solve the issue is using ORM like Entity Framework Core. You don't have to change any code but the Entity framework  providers. the same code will work for SQL, MySql, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQL Lite and so on.

few links that can help you : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore 
EF core providers : https://entityframework.net/supported-database-providers